# Button JQuery event only working once, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, api

```
<script>
        $("button").on("click", function() {
            $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1", function(json) {
                $(".author").html(json[0].title);
                $(".quote").html('"'+json[0].content+'"');
            });
        });

    </script>
```

---

**Situation:** I click, the data is loaded. I click again, nothing changes.

**Codepen:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxGgaZ

**Reference:** https://quotesondesign.com/api-v4-0/

Comment: Any errors in the console? Obviously visibly nothing will happen after the first getJSON call because you have already rendered the html the first time. If the request is not firing the second time then you need to check for errors.

Comment: Are you sure the data on the server is changing between clicks?

Comment: Is the button a child element of `.author` and/or `.quote`? If so you have to use [`event-delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for it to work

Comment: @empiric not a child.

Comment: @Zinc No erros.

Comment: @CamJohnson26 you can check by yourself with the url. It changes.

Comment: What is expected result? Is same response served? Can you create a stacksnippets or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate?

Comment: I get the same response everytime: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/k6849uw5/)

Comment: @guest271314 yes: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxGgaZ

Comment: @Coder1000 so what do you expect? The second time you click the data is overidden with the same response

Comment: @empiric I expect a random quote every time I click the button.

Comment: No `html` appears at codepen? _"I expect a random quote every time I click the button."_ Why do you have that expectation?

Comment: @Coder1000 then you should check the URL you are acessing, as it stands it currently serves alsways the same quote

Comment: @empiric Did you try the URL in your browser ? In my case, it returns a different quote every time.

Comment: On the codepen, if you enter the JS code in the JS area, instead of including it in the HTML, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the first response is being cached. You can solve that by adding a `$.ajaxSetup()` call which stops the caching:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: false
})
```

[**Updated Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMOgZd)

Alternatively, use `$.ajax()` and set `cache` directly in the settings:

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({  
      url: 'http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts',
      type: 'get',
      cache: false,
      data: 'filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1', 
      success: function(json) {
        $(".author").html(json[0].title);
        $(".quote").html('"' + json[0].content + '"');
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: That's what I was searching for, couldn't remember the exact code for this

Comment: Is resource served with CORS headers?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Still have not found a way to navigate codepen interface. stacksnippets uses `http://null` as origin, though was able to get resource using `<link>` element at plnkr. Note  `);` following `success` at `javascript` at Question.

Answer (score -1):

### Try Like This:

Maybe it's help you

```js
<script>
        $(document.body).on("click", 'button', function() {
            $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1", function(json) {
                $(".author").html(json[0].title);
                $(".quote").html('"'+json[0].content+'"');
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Did not change anything.